# Why there is no preflight Private Network Access request in chrome 99 and above?

Tags: google-chrome, private-network-access

According to this document: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/#preflight-requests. Chrome should enable preflight Private Network Access request since chrome 98. It seems that it was working correctly and I did a setup my configuration to this new feature.

But now in versions from this page (99, 100, 101): https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel/ in network console I am observing only regular requests in network console. Could someone please explain this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found information, that it has been rolled back for now.